# string.format syntax in c# and what it does?

Tags: c#, ssis

I am currently trying to modify a script for a SSIS project to import data from a dynamic .txt file (sometimes colums are added).

I am new to c# and the only problem in the script is that it contains a string format expression that I really can't graps so my question is:

What does this do?

```
string _Statement = String.Format ("{0}(?=(?:[^{1}]*{1}[^{1}]*{1})*(?![^{1}]*{1}))"
```

The parameters are

```
  {0} = First line in the file containing all the column headers
  {1} = Semicolon delimiter
```

Any help in this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The String.Format method here replaces all occurrences of {0} with `First line in the file containing all the column headers` and all occurrences of {1} with `Semicolon delimiter`. The resultant string will be a regular expression (regex) in this case.

Comment: Thank you that explains it! I guess that makes the question faulty due to the fact it is regex that I don't understand and not string.format. Now i have something to work with alteast!

Answer (score 3):

Since the same index is used repetitively, the same value is inserted.

So `{0}` will be replaced with

```
 First line in the file containing all the column headers
```

and all occurences of `{1}` will be replaced by

```
Semicolon delimiter
```

However, the code above seems to be incomplete since i'm missing the parameter list at the end of [`string.Format`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1ksz8yb7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Something like:

```
string _Statement = String.Format("{0}(?=(?:[^{1}]*{1}[^{1}]*{1})*(?![^{1}]*{1}))"
                                   , firstLine , ";");
```

Presuming that the line is: `TEST-LINE` this is the result:

```
"TEST-LINE(?=(?:[^;]*;[^;]*;)*(?![^;]*;))"
```

Comment: Seems that i can't upvote due to lack of reputation, but this answer explains the question. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

[String.Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.string.format%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) formats your string, so each parameter within {} will be replaced with a value which you also have to specify. In your example, all values with {0} will be replaced with

```
First line in the file containing all the column headers
```

and all values with {1} will be replaced with

```
Semicolon delimiter
```

You have to specify this two values as parameters to `String.Format`, so your code should look like:

```
string first = "col1,col2,col3";
string second = ";";
string _Statement = String.Format("{0}(?=(?:[^{1}]*{1}[^{1}]*{1})*(?![^{1}]*{1}))", first, second);
```

And the result will be

```
_Statement = "col1,col2,col3(?=(?:[^;]*;[^;]*;)*(?![^;]*;))";
```